# Idiomatic and Conventional F#

Tags: .net, f#

As of late I have been learning F#. Today I accumulated what I have learned so far to develop my first program - a script that counts the number of lines of code in a given Visual Studio project.

The code for said program is as follows:

```
#r "System.Xml.Linq"

open System
open System.IO
open System.Xml.Linq
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

printf "Enter solution path: "
let solutionPath = Console.ReadLine()
let solutionDirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(solutionPath)

let solutionText = File.ReadAllText(solutionPath)
let projectPaths  = 
    Regex.Matches(solutionText, "([^\"]*csproj)")
    |> Seq.cast<Match>
    |> Seq.map (fun m -> Path.Combine(solutionDirPath, m.Groups.[1].Value))

let codeFilePaths = 
    projectPaths
    |> Seq.map (fun projPath -> 
        let projectDirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(projPath)
        let document = XDocument.Load(projPath)
        document.Descendants()
            |> Seq.where (fun desc -> desc.Name.LocalName = "Compile")
            |> Seq.map (fun desc -> Path.Combine(projectDirPath, desc.FirstAttribute.Value)))
        |> Seq.concat

let locIsSignificant (loc : string) =
    let sanitizedLoc = loc.Trim()
    match sanitizedLoc with
    | ""  -> false
    | "{" -> false
    | "}" -> false
    | _   -> true

let totalLoc = 
    codeFilePaths
    |> Seq.sumBy (fun path ->
        File.ReadLines(path)
        |> Seq.where locIsSignificant
        |> Seq.length)

printfn "Total Loc: %i" totalLoc
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

I have tried write both clean and idiomatic code but I still have some concerns, namely:

- In this script, I introduce sequential intermediate bindings (`projectPaths`->`codeFilePaths`->`totalLoc`) however, the binding `locIsSignificant` feels like an interruption to this sequence. Have I arranged my code in an conventional way?
- Is my code as idomatic as can be? That is, could I make the code more expressive by using constructs or commands that I have not considered?

Of course, any additional feedback is welcome/encouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex.Matches(solutionText, "([^\"]*csproj)")
|> Seq.cast<Match>
|> Seq.map (fun m -> Path.Combine(solutionDirPath, m.Groups.[1].Value))
```

Why are you using groups? Since the whole match is a single group, you can remove the parentheses from the expression and then directly use `m.Value`.

Also, you should probably check that the name ends in `.csproj`, not just `csproj` and that it's actually the end of the file name.

---

```
let codeFilePaths = 
    projectPaths
    |> Seq.map (fun projPath -> 
        let projectDirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(projPath)
        let document = XDocument.Load(projPath)
        document.Descendants()
            |> Seq.where (fun desc -> desc.Name.LocalName = "Compile")
            |> Seq.map (fun desc -> Path.Combine(projectDirPath, desc.FirstAttribute.Value)))
        |> Seq.concat
```

- I think the complicated `map` lambda makes this hard to read, I would instead write it as a local named function. If you don't want to do that, at least make sure to indent your code properly (the first `|> Seq.map` and the `|> Seq.concat` should be on the same level).
- Instead of the `where`, you can use the overload of `Descendants` that accepts a node name (but this means you have to use XML namespaces).
- Instead of relying on the first attribute being the right one, I would access the attribute by name.

With all these changes and John Palmer's suggestion about `Seq.collect`, the code becomes:

```
let codeFilePaths = 
    let codeFilesForProject projPath = 
        let projectDirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(projPath)
        let document = XDocument.Load(projPath)
        let ns = XNamespace.Get "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
        document.Descendants(ns + "Compile")
            |> Seq.map (fun desc -> Path.Combine(projectDirPath, desc.Attribute(XName.Get "Include").Value))
    projectPaths |> Seq.collect codeFilesForProject
```

Answer (score 2):

This started as a comment and grew a little longer

I would maybe put `let locIsSignificant (loc : string) =` at the top of the file and change it to

```
let locIsSignificant (loc : string) =
    match loc.Trim() with
    | "" |"{" |"{" -> false
    | _   -> true
```

which is a little briefer and I think also shows the logic better.  In particular, it removes the auxiliary function from the logic flow by moving it to the top.

In `codepaths`, there are a few small changes that I would make.

replace

```
Seq.map ...
|> Seq.concat
```

with

```
Seq.collect
```

and change

```
        |> Seq.where (fun desc -> desc.Name.LocalName = "Compile")
        |> Seq.map (fun desc -> Path.Combine(projectDirPath, desc.FirstAttribute.Value)))
```

to

```
|> Seq.choose (fun desc -> 
    match desc.Name.LocalName with - 
    |"Compile" -> Some (Path.Combine(projectDirPath, desc.FirstAttribute.Value)) 
    | _ -> None))
```